# Solve the inequation for $x$

Tags: exponentiation

Solve for $x$ :

$ (x-1)^{2005} x^{2006} (x+1)^{2007} \le 0 $

I tried cases like : $ x-1 \le 0 $ , $ x \le 0 $ , $ x+1 \le 0 $

Comment: So what happened in those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's see if we can simplify your expression first:

$$ (x-1)^{2005} x^{2006} (x+1)^{2007} \le 0 $$
$$(x^2 - 1)^{2005}x^{2006}(x+1)^{2} \le 0$$

Think, first, what qualifies $x$ to be $\le 0$? If $x$ is $0$ or a negative number, correct?

Well, our expression can be $0$ if $x = -1, 1$

Thus, now lets look when our expression yields a negative number.

Therefore, look at the powers and see which ones could be negative:

$$(x^2 - 1)^{2005}x^{2006}(x+1)^{2} \le 0$$

We can see that $(x^2 - 1)^{2005}$ can only be negative, since the other $2$ terms have even powers, meaning they will only be positive.

Therefore, when is $(x^2 - 1)^{2005} \le 0$?

Well,

$$x^2 - 1 \le 0$$

$$x^2 \le 1$$

$$-1 \le x \le 1$$

And thus we arrive at our answer.

Comment: How did you get to $ (x^2-1)^{2005} x^{2006} (x+1)^2 $ ?

Comment: Well, first, understand that $(x+1)*(x-1) = (x^2-1)$ Both expressions were present in the equation above, so I combined them to get $(x^2-1)$. Note that $2005$ was the exponent common in both, so there was excess terms of $(x+1)$

Comment: Oh, thank you, I understood now

Comment: @Bogdan15 if you are content with my answer, then go ahead and upvote/accept it so other users understand the question has been solved.

Comment: I couldn't upvote because I don't have 15 reputation , sorry

Answer (score 0):

By the rule of signs,
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}\sgn{(x-1)^{2005}x^{2006}(x+1)^{2007}}=\sgn{(x-1)(x+1)}=\sgn(x^2-1), $$
hence the expression is $\;\le 0\;$ if and only if $\;-1\le x\le 1$.

Comment: Where did the $x$ go?

Comment: It has an *even* exponent, and that doesn't count.

Comment: @Arthur my explanation is a better explanation of Bernard's method of answering the question. Take a look at it.